# Get Collections stats in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

In earlier versions say MongoDB 2.6, the DBCollection class has this method getStats().

```
DBCollection.getStats()
```

In the new 3.x versions , we have a new class

> MongoCollection

and it has no method to get the statistics.

My question is how to get the statistics from the MongoCollection class

Comment: I understand that MongoCollection is an interface . But Mongodatabase.getCollection() returns  MongoCollection and am not sure how to retrieve the collection statistics in V3.2 java driver

Comment: I don't know if this will work or not, but have you tried seeing if it's possible to cast MongoCollection to a DBCollection?

Comment: Tried , didn't work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I've found a solution for you. It's a bit hackish, but from what I was reading, I couldn't find any other way around it. I was reading resources from Mongo and they were saying they simplifed the driver a bit and reduced the amount of available methods for a collection. I would guess that `getStats()` probably got cut since it doesn't seem like something you would do often, at least not programmatically for most use cases anyways. So here's what you *can* do:

First, a MongoDatabase object will have a `runCommand()` method. [3.0 driver docs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/)

If you look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/), you will get a list of all the commands you can execute with `runCommand()`.

One of those commands is [collStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#dbcmd.collStats). Based on the documentation, it looks like you will want to pass run command a Bson object that has the following form:

```
{
   collStats: <string>,
   scale: <int>,
   verbose: <boolean>
}
```

where the collStats is the string name of the collection for which you want stats. Scale is an optional field; you can read about it at the last link. Verbose defaults to false.

I don't know for sure that this will get you want you want, but it will at least get you pretty close. Let me know how it works out!

Comment: Fatnastic. Then could you please up-vote and accept my answer?